# Shadows follow?

Tags: game-engine, shadows

How can I make shadows for my player in my game everywhere on the map. I had the idea of making the sun follow the player wherever it goes. Unfortunatly, I don't know how. I want the sun to follow the player but never change the way it's globally rotated.
HOW???
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out myself:

The only (simple) thing I had to do is:

1. Select the lamp (which is set to the object in just the right way so if the object is not moving and the lamp is not moving, the shadow will work.
2. Shift-select the object that the lamp needs to follow.
3. Go into *Edit Mode* and select one vert.
4. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose (the only option) parent to vertex.
5. Go out of *Edit Mode* and done!

Answer (score 0):

Most basic way would be to parent the sun light to the player object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Maybe there are other methods using logic, maybe with a *parent* Actuator, I'm not very experienced with the game engine.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my question. The lamp should follow it Without Rotating through the scene.

Comment: Sorry I misread, missed that part. I've also tried doing that in the past but never got it to work. Maybe try a copy location constraint?